# UISearchBar doesn't using correct tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to implement a search bar for a UITableView but when i'm searching something, the table view that is displayed is not the table view i designed in the interface builder but one that has white background.

What I want is to keep the background colour I setted in the interface builder and not to shrink cells at the standard height when no data displayed.

How to do that? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using UISearchBarDisplay controller or UISearchBar?

Comment: I'm using a UISearchBarDisplay , sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: UISearchBarDisplayController has it's own tableView. That's the reason you are seeing that. I usually use UISearchBar class in this scenario. you probably have to do little extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this method to you view controller:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     
   didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 100; // your row heigh
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your BG color
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your BG color

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to put a checkmark on a cells from search results table? I tried this in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method but it's not working: [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

Comment: Try this: `UITableViewCell *myCell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
    if (myCell) {
        myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }`

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit tired :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a recent app and I never used the UISearchBarDisplay, just the search bar without the display controller. I set up the delegates for it in the .h file, and used these methods:

```
//Search Bar code
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{


}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     [searchBar resignFirstResponder];        
     [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

Will that work?

Comment: Sorry, have to get home and then testing. That methods are in some protocol i have to implement?

Comment: Ya, in the .h file you just need the  UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate> added. In my app, I just have the searchText setting a constant variable for a JSON feed link. Then when you click the search button(searchBarSearchButtonClicked method), it reloads that data in the tableView with the updated JSON link. It'll probably be different with yours on whats inside those methods idk.

Comment: I want to reload data after each letter added.

Comment: you could try put the '       
     [self.tableView reloadData];' in the textDidChange method. Not sure if that is a good way to go about doing that though.

Comment: You'll probably have to find a way to change the color of the background of the searchResultsTableView and change the height of the cells to be the same when there is no data.

Comment: I will try building a temporal array with a NSPredicate and store objects that contains letters from search box. Than use this temporal array as my data source.